# Changing data-icon in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I found a bunch of solutions online, but none of them are working for me. Basically, I want to toggle the icon of a button. Here's the HTML:

```
  <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
    <ul>
      <li><a data-icon="arrow-u">View suggestions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I tried all of these:

```
$(this).buttonMarkup({ icon: 'arrow-u' });
```

//

```
$(this).attr('data-icon','arrow-u');
$(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-arrow-d').addClass('ui-icon-arrow-u');
```

//

```
$(this).jqmData('icon','arrow-u');
```

However, for some reason, the child elements of the button all disappear after any of the above is ran (jQuery Mobile adds a bunch of `<span>`s inside the button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! I used `$(this).text('Hide suggestions')`, which removed all child elements. I changed it to `$(this).find('.ui-btn-text').text('Hide suggestions');` and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do that is:

```
$('#button').buttonMarkup({ icon: "home" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).attr('data-icon','arrow-u').button().trigger("refresh");
```

See related forum thread: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-dynamically-update-data-attributes

Answer (score 1):

These worked for me :

```
$("#yourButtonId .ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-gear").addClass("ui-icon-delete");

$(this).children("span").children(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-gear").addClass("ui-icon-delete");

$(this).find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-gear").addClass("ui-icon-save");
```

I don't know witch is the best, the last I think.